# Terminology: Co-completion of Met?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, terminology

In main-stream mathematical literature, the term metric space is reserved for $(X,d)$ where $X$ is a set and $d:X\times X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ satisfies the usual properties of a metric.  However, at times it is convenient to allow $d$ to take infinite values (for example if we would like to give meaning to a "co-product" of metric spaces).  In that case, what is the most standard terminology for such an "extended-real-valued" metric (i.e.: $codom(d)=[0,\infty]$)?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a standard terminology, but I have seen "infinite-valued metric" used (in Gerald Beer's _Topologies on Closed and Closed Convex Sets_).

Comment: Interesting, I have seen the same author (in *"The Structure of Extended Real-valued Metric Spaces"*) calling these objects extended real-valued metric spaces... now I'm even more confused.

Comment: I think "extended metric" is pretty standard. That's the term I used in my book *Lipschitz Algebras*.

Comment: True, yes I have seen that there.  Thanks Nik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that there is a standard name for such spaces (and hence for such generalised metrics). It is quite common to see the terms '$\infty$-metric space' and 'extended metric space' (or some slight modifications). However, the latter name is also used in a more general sense, where the metric $d$ is allowed to take values in any ordered set. Consequently, the former term can be seen as a special case of the latter, where the ordered set is the one of extended positive real numbers.